# Paginação utilizando PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Fiz uma paginação utilizando *PHP* que está funcionando perfeitamente, porém, ao chegar na penúltima página(10), a última página(11) ela vem como resultado "solto" e não vem estilizada como se fosse um "bug" Segue a imagem com o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

```
<ul class="pagination">

                <?php
            $pagina_atual = (!isset($_GET['p']))? 1 : $_GET['p']; 
            $max_results = 1;
            $prev = ($pagina_atual - 1);
            $next = ($pagina_atual + 1);
            $total_pages = ceil($paginas / $max_results);
            $pagination = '';
            if($paginas > 1) {
                $pagination .= '<li class="pagination_reborn"><a class="page " href="logacesso?p='.$prev.'">«</a></li> ';
            }

            for($i = max(1, $pagina_atual - 4); $i <= min($pagina_atual + 4, $total_pages); $i++) {
                if(($paginas) == $i)
                {
                    $pagination .= $i;

                }
                else
                {
                if($pagina_atual == $i) {
                        $pagination .='<li id="active_page" class="pagination_reborn"><a class="page" href="logacesso?p='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                } else {
                        $pagination .= '<li class="pagination_reborn"><a class="page" href="logacesso?p='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                    }
                }
            }
            if($pagina_atual < $total_pages)
            {
                $pagination .= '<li class="pagination_reborn"><a href="logacesso?p='.$next.'">»</a></li>';
            } 
            if($next == $i) {
                $pagination .= '<li class="pagination_reborn"><a class="page" href="logacesso?p='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
            }


            echo $pagination;

            ?>
```

Comment: Tente enumerar o For a partir do zero, já que 0 é um index.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve começar a enumerar as suas paginas a partir do zero(Somando +1 para a exibição).

O if para exibir o botão da pagina anterior precisa de mais uma regra para não exibir quando estiver na primeira pagina.

O primeiro if de dentro do for não é necessário, sendo que você só possui dois casos, pagina ativa e não ativa.

O ultimo if não é necessário pois nunca será chamado.

```
$pagina_atual = (!isset($_GET['p'])) ? 1 : $_GET['p'];
$max_results = 1;
$prev = ($pagina_atual - 1);
$next = ($pagina_atual + 1);
$total_pages = ceil($paginas / $max_results);
$pagination = '';

if ($paginas > 1 && $pagina_atual > 1) {
    $pagination .= '<li class="pagination_reborn"><a class="page " href="logacesso?p=' . $prev . '">«</a></li> ';
}

for ($i = max(0, $pagina_atual - 4); $i < min($pagina_atual + 4, $total_pages); $i++) {
    $page = $i + 1;

    if ($pagina_atual == $page) {
        $pagination .= '<li id="active_page" class="pagination_reborn"><a class="page" href="logacesso?p=' . $page . '">' . $page . ' ativo</a></li>';
    } else {
        $pagination .= '<li class="pagination_reborn"><a class="page" href="logacesso?p=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a></li>';
    }
}
if ($pagina_atual < $total_pages) {
    $pagination .= '<li class="pagination_reborn"><a href="logacesso?p=' . $next . '">»</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: Continua com mesmo erro ;/ Aparece o ultimo número.

Comment: @matheus teste novamente, veja se não esqueceu de algo, verifiquei o código linha a linha e está ok